# Relative movement for independant bullets (HTML5/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cursor

I need some help with this code. The game I am making atm is a top down 2d game. My character can already move and shoot a bullet. The problem im facing is making the bullet shoot towards the direction of the cursor.

I have that done already but the problem is that when I shoot multiple bullets, all the bullets change direction to go towards my cursor. What i am thinking that needs to be done is every bullet needs to be assigned it's specefic path so it will not change when i shoot another bullet. The bullet is an object already so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
Bullet.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.drawX += (mouseX - this.drawX) * 0.01 ;
    this.drawY += (mouseY - this.drawY) * 0.01 ;
    ctxbullet.drawImage(imgSprite, this.srcX, this.srcY, 
        this.width, this.height, this.drawX, this.drawY, 10, 8);
};
```

As you can see every Bullet follows the rules and logic here.

Another problem is that the bullet doesn't go at a constant speed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're looking for an algorithm that imitates the trajectory of a bullet, this should help - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/19586

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mouseX and mouseY properties you are using in that function are defined elsewhere. This means as that variable gets updated outside of this function, the numbers you are using to update drawX and drawY will also be changing.

What you need to do is keep track of local copies of mouseX and mouseY at the time of creation. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but I will take some guesses.

```
function Bullet(x, y) {
    this.srcX = x;
    this.srcY = y;
    // keep track of original mouse coordinates
    this.mouseX = mouseX;
    this.mouseY = mouseY;
}

Bullet.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.drawX += (this.mouseX - this.drawX) * 0.01;
    this.drawY += (this.mouseY - this.drawY) * 0.01;
    ctxbullet.drawImage(
        imgSprite,
        this.srcX,  this.srcY,
        this.width, this.height,
        this.drawX, this.drawY,
        10, 8
    );
};
```

This will make sure that bullets are always travelling towards the mouse coordinates when they were created, but you quickly run into another problem. Since the speed is relative to the bullets distance from those mouse coordinates (which is why you are experiencing an inconsistent speed) the bullets are going to slow to a stop at the mouse coordinates.

What you need to do is create a vector from the src point to the mouse point at a desired speed. This will allow the bullet to follow that vector for infinity (but you know, not actually infinity, hopefully you remove it once its out of bounds).

```
function Bullet(x, y) {
    var dX = mouseX - x,
        dY = mouseY - y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY)
    ;
    // we want our deltas to be proportions of the total distance
    this.dX = dX / dist;
    this.dY = dY / dist;
    this.speed = 5; // arbitrary number
}

Bullet.prototype.draw = function() {
    // I didn't test this, but I think it works
    this.drawX += this.dX * this.speed;
    this.drawY += this.dY * this.speed;
    ctxbullet.drawImage(
        imgSprite,
        this.srcX,  this.srcY,
        this.width, this.height,
        this.drawX, this.drawY,
        10, 8
    );
}
```

Comment: The problem im getting is it says Dx and Dy are undefined

Comment: Did you change you're code to pass the x and y coordinates when you create a bullet? new Bullet(x, y) instead of new Bullet()?

Comment: what does this x and y represent?